# PHP - Replacing content of variable to names

Tags: php, arrays, variables, replace

How can I replace a numbers in a variable - to output a name instead?

My variable called @location - contains some numbers either: 17, 49, 11, 13.
I need to output a name instead: Sal, Room, Entre, Hall

I did try this with no success - very new to PHP:

```
<?php

$location = [
  '17' => 'Sal',
  '49' => 'Room',
  '11' => 'Entre',
  '13' => 'Hall',
  
];

?>

Echo $location;
```

Comment: This is unclear. You want to "output a name" but based on what?

Comment: Asking `$selectedValue = 17; echo $location[$selectedValue];`?